# Constraint Layout group multiple views as a single item in the chain

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to achieve the following layout while using ConstraintLayout chaining and not use any additional layouts. All the spacing between views should be equal.

[image: 1]

The similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48461067/constraint-layout-grouping-together-layouts-in-chains) but the spacing between views are not kept equal.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, desired behavior cannot be achieved with a flat view hierarchy without any additional views and nesting.

But there is one workaround for a special case, where you know the width of views 3 and 4 beforehand. For that workaround, you'll need to add an additional invisible view underneath your `view 3` and `view 4`.
Attaching the sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/stub_view"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/stub_view"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/view5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/stub_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view4"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/stub_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view5"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/stub_view"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you don't know the exact width of `View 3` and `View 4` at the runtime - you could use one more hack and set the LayoutChangeListeners to these views to monitor their width and change the width of the stub view accordingly in the runtime. **But I wouldn't recommend** using the second workaround as it will most likely add more code that smells into your codebase.

Before you'd use this workaround please consider using views nesting and put `View 3` and `View 4` into one `LinearLayout` (or other `ViewGroup` of your choice).

Comment: `you'll need to add an additional invisible view underneath your view 3 and view 4` an ideal solution for a lot of situations for example [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg5NX.png). to align 2,3 at the same time with 4 will be impossible, but grouping them with invisible view will just help doing the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `GuideLineConstraint` like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="147dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="293dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="311dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button4" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This applies only if I can calculate the percentage of the guideline. If the width of the views are unknown, this is not possible.